# Spring RESTful Service

Tags: spring-mvc

I am unable to hit a Spring rest service I have created. I am new to spring and have been trying to follow the tutorials and find examples online. I am unable to determine what I am doing incorrectly.

Web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Friend List</display-name>

  <servlet>
       <servlet-name>friendlist</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>friendlist</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/friend-list/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

friend-list-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="demo.model"/>
</beans>
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package demo.model;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorld {

    public HelloWorld() {}

    @RequestMapping("/hello")   
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

I am trying to return just the text, not a view, which is the reason I have used a @RestController. I am running Java JDK 7, Eclipse Luna, and Tomcat 7. I have tried hitting localhost:8080/friend-list/hello and get a 404. Also, I have inserted a @RequestMapping("/friend-list") above the header of the class and also received 404s going to both /friend-list/hello and /friend-list/friend-list/hello.

Tomcat Log:

```
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler 'helloWorld'
Jul 23, 2014 8:20:35 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello.*] onto handler 'helloWorld'
Jul 23, 2014 8:20:35 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello/] onto handler 'helloWorld'
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>friend-list</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>friend-list Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <finalName>friend-list</finalName>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are new to Spring and you are wanting to do RESTFUL then go checkout Spring BOOT. You can thank me later ;) Lots of examples and pretty easy to understand (IMHO). From above you might be missing a dash. <servlet-name>friend-list</servlet-name>

Comment: Please include your POM.xml

Comment: POM.xml added to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

*You need to update your web.xml: (hyphen is important with the servlet name)

> ```
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>friend-list</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
>    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>friend-list</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/friend-list/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

*For Hello World you are missing a few things.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    public HelloWorld() {
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

RequestMapping for the Resource then you are going to want to map the resource methods.
ResponseBody was missing as well

*Once your app is up and running you should be able to hit: 
    localhost:8080/myapp/friend-list/hello

Where myapp is whatever you named your app. 
I like using postman ( Chrome plugin and easy to us.)

*http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/2/ Excellent tutorial in regards to Spring and REST.

Answer (score 0):

Spring wasn't loading your @RestController because the spring configuration file was not having a filename that matched the name of your servlet. So if your servlet name in Web.xml is friendlist, then your spring configuration file should be named friendlist-servlet.xml